# Perl: regex for conditional replace?

Tags: regex, perl

in this string

```
ab<(CN)cdXYlm<(CI)efgXYop<(CN)zXYklmn<(CI)efgXYuvw<
```

I want to replace each substring between `XY` and `<` by either ONE or TWO depending on characters between previous brackets:

if `XY` after `(CN)` replace substring by `ONE`

if `XY` after `(CI)` replace substring by `TWO`

So the result should be:

```
ab<(CN)cdONE<(CI)efgTWO<(CN)zONE<(CI)efgTWO<
```

`XY` and following characters should be replaced but not angle bracket `<`.

This is for modifying HTML and arbitrary characters can occur between `XY` and `<`.
I guess I need two regex for (CN) and (CI).

```
# This one replaces just all XY:   
my $s = 'ab<(CN)cdXYlm<(CI)efgXYop<(CN)zXYklmn<(CI)efgXYuvw<';
$s =~ s/(XY(.*?))</ONE/g;    
# But how to add the conditions to the regex?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need two regexes. Capture the `C[NI]` and retrieve the corresponding replacement value from a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = 'ab<(CN)cdXYlm<(CI)efgXYop<(CN)zXYklmn<(CI)efgXYuvw<';

my %replace = (CN => 'ONE', CI => 'TWO');

$s =~ s/(\((C[NI])\).*?)XY.*?</$1$replace{$2}</g;

my $exp = 'ab<(CN)cdONE<(CI)efgTWO<(CN)zONE<(CI)efgTWO<';

use Test::More tests => 1;
is $s, $exp;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Actually I need more character combinations between the brackets, so I replaced (C[NI]) by (CN|CO|IN)

Comment: @Fabian_Z071: If you also added a new pair into the %replace hash, everything should work :-)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this expression or maybe a modified version of that might work, not sure though:

```
([a-z]{2}<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{2})([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{3})([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z])([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{3})([^<]+)<
```

#### Test

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'ab<(CN)cdXYlm<(CI)efgXYop<(CN)zXYklmn<(CI)efgXYuvw<';
my $regex = qr/([a-z]{2}<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{2})([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{3})([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z])([^<]+)(<\([A-Z]{2}\)[a-z]{3})([^<]+)</mp;
my $subst = '"$1ONE$3TWO$5ONE$7TWO<"';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rgee;

print $result;
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qu7nxg/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Qu7nxg/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: Note that Perl interpolates just once in the replacement part, i.e. `$subst` will be interpolated, but not `$1` it contains.

Comment: It works with `my $subst = '"$1ONE$3TWO$5ONE$7TWO<"';` and `/rgee`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line regex using `/e` and ternary operator `?` in the `/replace/`.
`/r` option returns the resulting string, in effect this would keep the original string `$s` unmodified.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s ='ab<(CN)cdXYlm<(CI)efgXYop<(CN)zXYklmn<(CI)efgXYuvw<';
print (($s=~s/\(([^)]+)\)([^(]+)XY[^(]+</"($1)$2".(($1 eq CN)?ONE:TWO)."<"/gre)."\n");
```

#### Output:

```
ab<(CN)cdONE<(CI)efgTWO<(CN)zONE<(CI)efgTWO<
```